# Is there a SAPI module for PHP 5 for supporting the thttpd web server?

Tags: php, sapi, thttpd

Is there a SAPI module for PHP 5 for supporting the thttpd web server?
Oddly, the one included on PHP 5.2.6 source is for PHP 4.x.

Thanks,
Kenneth

Comment: Any reason to /abuse/ the poor thttpd to run PHP? :)

Comment: The reason is simple. :)
We want to create web applications using PHP, and the current HTTP server we have is thttpd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thttpd SAPI that ships with PHP 5 works.  Ignore the README where it says "PHP 4".

However, understand that PHP for thttpd is single-threaded.  All other requests will stall while PHP is executing.  This is might be acceptable for a low traffic site or embedded application.  If not, I recommend trying [nginx](http://nginx.net/), another lightweight web server that runs PHP in a separate process via FastCGI.